# Convert EXE or other file to a text-format and back

Tags: windows, vbscript, binary, base64, exe

What i want to do is, transfer some exe files from my local PC to a server thro RDP.
Copy-Pasting the file doesnt work and i dont want to do it this way.

What i tried to do was, open the exe in notepad in my local PC, copy the contents and paste them in a text file in the server and then rename to .exe. This, however did not work. It corrupted the exe file.

Is there any other way to convert the exe/binary file into a series of strings only so that i can copy paste to the server, and then decode it back to the exe without corrupting it?

Will base64 work?

(I can to use VBScript to encode/decode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emails are using base64 encoding to transfer files. So yes, base64 will work.

Here the prove (on Linux) with a simple text file:

```
$ echo -n "abc" > file
$ hexdump file 
0000000 6261 0063                              
0000003
$ sha1sum file 
a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d  file
$ base64 ./file > BASE64
$ base64 --decode < BASE64 > newFile
$ sha1sum newFile 
a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d  newFile
```

Comment: How do i open the file in vbscript? OpenTextFile will again open it as a text file and might not read the unicode/binary characters

Answer (score 0):

base64 encoding should work. It would be easier to just [connect one of your local drives](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313292) in the RDP session, though.

Comment: i cannot connect drives as the RDP i access is through citrix which is in a completely different domain

Comment: Citrix does not use RDP. It uses its own protocol (ICA). However, that too does allow you to connect local drives. In fact it should by default auto-connect all your local drives, unless administratively prohibited, in which case you should be talking to an administrator about what you're trying to do.